# Android - Duplicate class error when installing Firebase + Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

I've followed the steps for installing Firebase and Crashlytics to a project, such as adding the google-services.json, the correct plugins and dependencies and whenever I try to compile I'm stuck with the following error output:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zza found in modules jetified-play-services-base-15.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-15.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc found in modules jetified-play-services-base-15.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzd found in modules jetified-play-services-base-15.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zza found in modules jetified-play-services-base-15.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-15.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-15.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzc found in modules jetified-play-services-base-15.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

This error goes away when I comment out the following lines:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
```

Here are all my project build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

and these are my app level dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.4"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.3"
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.2"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9'

    implementation 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.arcadefire:nice-spinner:1.4.4'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.3.1'

    //Font Solution
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'

    implementation 'me.saket:better-link-movement-method:2.2.0'

    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:5.1.0'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.16.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.yoti.mobile.android.sdk:yoti-sdk-doc-scan:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:9.1.1'

    //For Bullet Lists
    implementation 'com.github.fueled:snippety:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.realexpayments.hpp.sdk:rxp-hpp-android:2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.corouteam:GlideToVectorYou:v2.0.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains:markdown:0.2.4"
    implementation 'com.github.forresthopkinsa:StompProtocolAndroid:17.11.0'


}
```

Comment: Did you applied plugin 'id 'com.google.gms.google-services' '

Comment: same here, no solution found